# kubernetes общение сервисов

Tags: devops, kubernetes, микросервисы, deploy

начал изучать kubernetes для работы и такой вопрос. Есть 2 сервиса: сервис А и сервис Б. Сервис Б обращается к сервису А, для этого мы чётко должны сказать в коде сервису Б порт и ip сервиса А. Но как это реализовать для сети kubernetes? Насколько я понял, у каждого пода свой IP и port(при рестарте меняются, да еще и таких подов может быть n количество на k нодах). Вопрос в чём, как это общение реализовано в коде?
Просто если в сервисе Б указывать четко x.x.x.x:zzzz сервиса А, то:

1. скорее всего он этого не найдет
2. как же тогда подключить распределителя нагрузки

В самой архитектуре k8s примерно всё понятно, непонятно только как задать общение...
Извиняюсь, если такой вопрос был, но найти ответа не могу.

Answer (score 0):

Для каждого сервиса в k8s создается DNS запись следующего типа:

```
service_name.namespace.svc.cluster.local
```

Дополнительная информация о DNS в k8s тут:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/